# Connect to remote MySql server with XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I have an script that i want it to run for more that 5 minutes. But my current hosting service does not allow me to modify the max_time_limit in the php.ini (That is set to 2 minutes)...
So i thought that i could run the script with XAMPP and send the data to my database but i cant connect to the remote database.

This is the code for the connection:

```
$servername = "217.70.186.108"; //I've also tried with the name of the webpage (metagame.gg)
$username = "the_username"; //the username is not root since I've read that root can only connect from localhost. This user has all privileges. This user was created with the permision to be connected from any server (%)
$password = "the_password";
$dbname = "the_db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

It displays this error:

> Connection failed: An error occurred during the attempt to connect because the connected party did not properly responded after a period of time, or failed in the established connection because connected host has failed to respond.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Well, _do_ you have remote access? Usually that is blocked by firewalls for good reasons... Have a try with the telnet utility: `telnet 217.70.186.108 3306` - what result do you get?

Comment: You would need to create an account on the servers MYSQL that is allowed to connect from a remote location. Many hosting companies do not allow this _for obvious security reasons_ You will have to check that yours allows this and then ask how to do it.

Comment: If you have SSH access to the server, you can probably copy the script to the server and run it from within the SSH terminal. PHP CLI may well be available that way